# Perl Build ignores destdir

Tags: perl

I am try to create a RPM for the Perl Module `YAML::Tiny` and in my spec file I have this ...

```
%build
/usr/perl/bin/perl Build.PL INSTALLDIRS=vendor
./Build
./Build test
%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
./Build install destdir=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```

... and when I run `rpmbuild` I get this error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/perl-5.14.1/lib/red_perl/YAML'
mkdir /usr/perl-5.14.1/lib/red_perl/YAML: Permission denied at /usr/perl-5.14.1/lib/5.14.1/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 494

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The install should be writing to my `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` directory not `/usr/perl*`

Comment: yes `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` is set to my `~/perl-YAML-Tiny/BUILDROOT/perl-YAML-Tiny/BUILDROOT/perl-YAML-Tiny-1.56-1-x86_64` and I have perms to write to that directory.  But `./Build install destdir=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` is being ignored and `./Build install` is try to write to `/usr/perl-5.14.1/lib/red_perl/YAML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[YAML::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/release/YAML-Tiny) currently uses [Module::Build::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aTiny) for installation.  That isn't as flexible about how you pass parameters.  To quote [its docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aTiny#Incompatibilities):

> Module::Build has an extremely permissive way of argument handling, Module::Build::Tiny only supports a (sane) subset of that. In particular, `./Build destdir=/foo` does not work, you will need to pass it as `./Build --destdir=/foo`.

(This is so it can outsource argument parsing to [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt%3a%3aLong) instead of having to include a custom command-line parser like [Module::Build](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aBuild) does.)

So your spec should look like this:

```
%build
/usr/perl/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs=vendor
./Build
./Build test
%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
./Build install --destdir=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```